# libclang clang_getSpellingLocation access violation

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder, libclang

I'm trying to start a tutorial about libclang library, but I get an access violation when calling the function `clang_getSpellingLocation()`. Other information about the error is correctly reported with error count, line and column.

My environment: C++Builder XE pro, Windows 7 32bit, LLVM 3.4, libCLang.lib converted
   using coff2omf, libCLang.dll.

I tested the same code on visual C++ 2010 and it works correctly.

Please could anyone you help me about this issue?

My simple code

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm8::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

    unsigned line, column;
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);

    const  char  * args []  =  {
    "-I/usr/include" ,
    "-I."
    };

    int  numArgs  =  sizeof ( args )  /  sizeof ( * args );

  CXTranslationUnit tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, "G:\\projects\\LibCLang  \\File2.cpp", args, numArgs, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

  unsigned  diagnosticCount  =  clang_getNumDiagnostics ( tu );

  for ( unsigned  i  =  0 ;  i  <  diagnosticCount ;  i++ )
  {
      CXDiagnostic  diagnostic   =  clang_getDiagnostic ( tu ,  i );
      CXSourceLocation location = clang_getDiagnosticLocation(diagnostic);
      clang_getSpellingLocation(location, NULL, &line, &column, NULL);
      CXString text = clang_getDiagnosticSpelling(diagnostic);
      UnicodeString s = clang_getCString(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: I belive that the access violation error could depend by the call convention, in fact the libclang.dll uses the __cdecl convention, while a standard DLL requires __stdcall. if I change the return type of the function from CXString type to the void, all work correctly, but obviously I can not read the returned text. Please, Please could anyone you help me about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the AV is on `clang_getSpellingLocation()` and not `clang_getDiagnosticSpelling()`?

When using the `__cdecl` calling convention, compilers from different vendors are allowed to do whatever they want when it comes to returning a structure by value when the size of the structure is <= 8 bytes.  In the case of `clang_getDiagnosticSpelling()`, `CXString` is 8 bytes in a 32bit environment.  Some compilers, like Visual C++, return the contents of an 8-byte structure directly in the `EAX:EDX` CPU registers, whereas other compilers, like C++Builder, use a hidden output parameter that passes a reference to a temp structure.

`clang_getDiagnosticSpelling()` (and other similar functions) return a `CXString` using `EAX:EDX`, but C++Builder uses a hidden parameter instead.  There is a simple workaround for that.  C++Builder expects a `__cdecl` function to return an `__int64` using `EAX:EDX`, and since `CXString` and `__int64` are the same size in 32bit, you can do the following:

```
typedef __int64 __cdecl (*clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack)(CXDiagnostic);

//CXString text = clang_getDiagnosticSpelling(diagnostic);
clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack func = reinterpret_cast<clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack>(&clang_getDiagnosticSpelling);
__int64 tmp = func(diagnostic);
CXString text = reinterpret_cast<CXString&>(tmp);
```

Alternatively, you can utilize C++Builder's `_EAX` and `_EDX` intrinsics:

```
typedef void __cdecl (*clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack)(CXDiagnostic);

//CXString text = clang_getDiagnosticSpelling(diagnostic);
clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack func = reinterpret_cast<clang_getDiagnosticSpellingHack>(&clang_getDiagnosticSpelling);
CXString text;
func(diagnostic);
text.ptr_data = (void*) _EAX;
text.int_data = _EDX;
```

As for `clang_getSpellingLocation()`, I would not expect there to be such a mismatch in conventions since it has no return value, unless `clang_getSpellingLocation()` were compiled to accept its `CXSourceLocation` parameter differently than how C++Builder is passing it.  C++Builder pushes all three data values from `CXSourceLocation` directly on the call stack.  You would have to look at the disassembly of `clang_getSpellingLocation()` to see how it is actually accessing the values of its `CXSourceLocation` parameter, and then adjust your C++Builder code accordingly if needed.

You should also double-check how `clang_getDiagnosticLocation()` is returning its `CXSourceLocation` to make sure that it matches how C++Builder expects it to be returned (via a hidden output parameter by reference) to ensure that memory is not being corrupted before `clang_getSpellingLocation()` is being called.  So it is possible that `clang_getSpellingLocation()` itself might not be the culprit.  Hard to say without seeing the disassembly for both `clang_getDiagnosticLocation()` and `clang_getSpellingLocation()` (I have seen the disassembly for functions that return `CXString`, that is how I know for sure that clang uses `EAX:EDX` for that).